# Approximation of an integral (another)

Tags: integration, approximation

I am reading a book and it makes me nuts. The authors say that there is a "well-known approximation", but I don't know it. I'll cite their passage:

*"Next, using the well-known approximation of the integral*

$\int_{a(t)} ^{a(t)+\delta a(t)} \beta(\tau)m(\tau)d\tau=\beta(a(t))m(a(t))\delta a(t)+o(\delta a(t))$

..."

Source: N. Hritonenko and Yu. Yatsenko, Mathematical Modeling in Economics, Ecology and the Environment, 2nd Edition, Springer, New York/Berlin, 2013, 296p· The passage is on **page 127**.

Would someone be so kind and answer me the following questions:
- Which approximation rule is this?
- Is there a nice textbook, in which it is simple explained?
Thx
Kerim

Comment: Looks like a Riemann sum approximation with one term ($n=1).  The error term $o(\delta a(t))$ looks like wishful thinking, or maybe is implied by context not supplied here.

Comment: That brought onto the right track. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $f(x)$ is a reasonable function, we have  $\;\int_a^b f(x)dx \approx f(a)(b-a)\;$ as a reasonable approximation. Another way of writing the approximation is $\int_a^b f(x)dx = f(a)(b-a) + o(b-a)$ using [little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Notice that here $f(a)$ can be replaced by $f(c)$ for **any** $c\in[a,b].$

Comment: That approximation assumes that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

"$\delta$" is usually used to indicate a small, often infinitesimal, change in something, so $\delta(a(\tau))$ is a small change in $a(\tau)$. Thus,
$$
\int_{a(t)}^{a(t)+\delta(a(t))}\beta(\tau)m(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau\tag1
$$
is the integral of $\beta(\tau)m(\tau)$ over the infinitesimal interval
$$
\left[a(t),a(t)+\delta(a(t))\right]\tag2
$$
Assuming $\beta(\tau)m(\tau)$ is continuous, we have
$$
\beta(\tau)m(\tau)=\beta(a(t))m(a(t))+o(1)\tag3
$$
over the interval in $(2)$, where $o(1)\to0$ as $\delta(a(t))\to0$. Integrating the approximation in $(3)$, we get
$$
\int_{a(t)}^{a(t)+\delta(a(t))}\beta(\tau)m(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau=\beta(a(t))m(a(t))\delta(a(t))+o(\delta(a(t)))\tag4
$$